# Tab Not working for Write-host command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to write this piece of code and as far as I can tell everything seems correct but when it displays the `t isn't tabbing and only creating a single space for some of the write-hosts:

```
Write-Host "`r`n`r`n        Categories | $($oldValues.cluster)`t$($newValues.cluster)`t | % Used if Migrated" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-host "    Total MEM (GB) | $($oldValues.TotalMEM)`t$($newValues.TotalMEM)`t | %"          
Write-host "     Used MEM (GB) | $($oldValues.UsedMEM)`t$($newValues.UsedMEM)`t | " -ForegroundColor $(if(($($oldValues.UsedMEM) + $($newValues.UsedMEM))/$($newValues.TotalMEM) -lt 95) {'Green'} else {'Red'}) 
Write-host "    Total CPU (GH) | $($oldValues.TotalCPU)`t$($newValues.TotalCPU)`t | "
Write-host "     Used CPU (GH) | $($oldValues.UsedCPU)`t$($newValues.UsedCPU)`t | " -ForegroundColor $(if(($($oldValues.UsedCPU) + $($newValues.UsedCPU))/$($newValues.TotalCPU) -lt 95) {'Green'} else {'Red'}) 
Write-host "Total Storage (GB) | $($oldValues.TotalStorage)`t$($newValues.TotalStorage)`t | "
Write-host " Used Storage (GB) | $($oldValues.UsedStorage)`t$($newValues.UsedStorage)`t | " -ForegroundColor $(if(($($oldValues.UsedStorage) + $($newValues.UsedStorage))/$($newValues.TotalStorage) -lt 95) {'Green'} else {'Red'})
```

This is the output I get:

```
        Categories | OLD Clus   NEW Clus | % Used if Migrated
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total MEM (GB) | 1533       3067     | %
     Used MEM (GB) | 24 113      |
    Total CPU (GH) | 110        294      |
     Used CPU (GH) | 2  6        |
Total Storage (GB) | 30719      10000    |
 Used Storage (GB) | 570        317      |
```

I cannot get Used MEM/CPU to tab

Comment: are you aware that this is very simple to accomplish by creating a single object then you can use `Format-Table -AutoSize` ? any particular reason you're trying to reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: @Santiago, good point in general, but note the _conditional coloring_ in the output.

Comment: Yes I originally started with the format table but needed more customizing that led to this

Comment: What sort of customizing does this allow you to have that an object does not? coloring is very easily accomplished by prepending a VT sequence before the string.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it correct but the position of the next tab stop depends on the current position of the cursor. Maybe that's why some of the tabs are only one character wide.  You would need to take the length of the strings you want to display into account. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Olaf - I see what you mean, as long as I have a number that is larger than 3 chars then it tabs correctly.... how unfortunate.....

** EDIT **
Used Math to round to 2 decimal places and problem solved, its not the best solution but it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @BobJohnson You may post your solution as answer for others looking for a solution for the same or a similar issue. 

Comment: Why not using a table instead? A PSCustomObject. Such as `$Table; <Your code>; $Table += [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = Value, Name2 = Value2 }`. And the call out the table with $Table